# How to correctly call on onsubmit event using IWebBrowser2 interfaces (using c++)

Tags: c++, html, com, atl

I'm trying to call the onsubmit programmatically without clicking in the form button.

First i try to simply call the submit function of the IHTMLFormElement interface but the form does not correctly processed the input data:

```
CComPtr<IHTMLFormElement> ppvForm;
ppvForm->submit();
```

I read in the documentation and it says that the submit function do not call the onsubmit event, then i try to call the onsubmit event by using the IDispatch invoke method provided by the get_onsubmit of the IHTMLFormElement interface:

```
CComPtr<IHTMLFormElement> ppvForm;
...
_variant_t vResult;
_variant_t tvar;
hResult = ppvForm->get_onsubmit(&tvar); // <<< i get a NULL VARIANT here 

DISPPARAMS params = {0};
hResult = tvar.pdispVal->Invoke(
    DISPID_VALUE, 
    IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 
    DISPATCH_METHOD, 
    &params, 
    &vResult, 
    NULL, 
    NULL);
if( SUCCEEDED(hResult) )
...
```

But the ppvForm->get_onsubmit call return S_OK with a NULL variant... (don't know why?!)

And in the end tried the fireEvent from the IHTMLDocument4 interface:

```
HRESULT hrRes=S_FALSE;
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument4> piDoc;
...
VARIANT_BOOL varRet;
CComPtr<IHTMLEventObj>pEvent;
hrRes=piDoc->createEventObject(NULL, &pEvent);

_variant_t vtEvent(pEvent);
hrRes=piDoc->fireEvent(_bstr_t(_T("onsubmit")), &vtEvent, &varRet);
```

The fireEvent now returns always E_INVALIDARG! don't know why? don't know if i need to put something in the vtEvent or the "onsubmit" string is invalid, don't know.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `get_onsubmit()` is returning S_OK and a NULL handler, then there is simply no onsubmit event handler assigned to the form to begin with.

Comment: It's the only form in the html page, and if i call the click() function on the IHTMLElement (html button elment) all process is done correctly (but this requires that the user makes a choice in a message box, and i'm trying to avoid this message box)
The button code:

function enviar()
{
 if (submitthis())
 if (confirm("Confirmation of the action?"))
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
} 

As you can see i only want to do the same thing as the 'document.getElementById('form1').submit();' statement...

Comment: Since the message box is being displayed by a button's onclick event and not the form's onsubmit event, just submitting the form programmably bypasses the message box.  So what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is that the submit (ppvForm->submit(); the first form) do not properly execute because not all the required params were not filled, i already set all the params and the submit now works fine (using the first form). Thanks to point me in the right direction Remy Lebeau.